# How to change mp3 file to wav file in node.js

Tags: fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to convert mp3 file to wav file but I am not getting idea how to do that, I tried using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) library but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally figured it out using 'fluent-ffmpeg' library. Here is my code.

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
let track = './source.mp3';//your path to source file

ffmpeg(track)
.toFormat('wav')
.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
})
.on('progress', (progress) => {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
    console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Processing finished !');
})
.save('./hello.wav');//path where you want to save your file
```

if you are facing

```
An error occurred: Cannot find ffmpeg
```

then add the `ffmpeg` path in system environment variables. Your VSCode still may dont recognise the ffmpeg command so in that case re-start VSCode.

Comment: Im getting error : 
`An error occurred: Cannot find ffmpeg`.

Comment: No error with just `var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');` . Only erroring when I use it.

Comment: make sure ffmpeg is installed in system and executable from everywhere and second thing is make sure that 'fluent-ffmpeg' npm package is also installed in project.

Comment: Both are reinstalled. I added the path in System Environment Variables also (for ffmpeg). Now I'm getting error : ` ENOENTspawn C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)`

Comment: ok do one thing just go to console and try to execute some ffmpeg command. Whatever you r telling it should do the work or if can you please show me your source then I can resolve issue.

Comment: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

please refer this link to set properly fluent-ffmpeg library

Comment: ffmpeg works from the command .. The issue was `.setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")` Now I am able to convert the file. I am trying to figure out .. how to convert the uploaded file from a form. Can you help please? How to access the file from Multer?

Comment: Download that file locally somewhere and access it directly it's simple.

Comment: Do you want me to give sample code? let me know .. just use request module and download at some destination.

Comment: I'll be very grateful if you could give a sample code. I've posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227600/how-to-access-uploaded-file-from-multer". Please have a look .. I'm very confused as to how to integrate `ffmpeg` in `multer-s3` module. Thanks.

Comment: Im able to upload the file with `multer` and convert it with `ffmpeg`. That part is working. But its only `multer` and not `multer-s3`. How can I upload the converted `.mp4` to `S3`? Please help.

Comment: give me ur email i'll forward you the code to upload to s3

Comment: I replied just check :)

Comment: so ffmpeg should be insatlled on the node server!!! is there any other way to solve this?? any library that works without installed extra executable on server?